# PHP and MYSQL group results from database and display

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem when I want to group results from database. I have to tables 1)**devices** and 2)**device_groups**. I used INNER JOIN to get related data.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'name', 'pass', 'tbl');


$qry = "
        SELECT g.id as groupId, g.name as groupName, d.device_id
        FROM librenms.devices as d
        INNER JOIN librenms.device_groups as g
                ON d.hostname LIKE  CONCAT('%', mysql.SPLIT_STR(g.pattern, '\"', 2), '%')
        WHERE g.pattern LIKE '_devices.hostname%'
        ORDER BY g.id
";


$qid = $mysqli->query($qry);
```

The following code looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Group Name</th>
    <th>Device ID</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = $qid->fetch_assoc()){
    $deviceId = split(",",$row["device_id"]);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["groupName"] ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $deviceId[0]; array_shift($deviceId) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach( $deviceId as $device){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $device ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

And I get the result like this:

```
Group Name  | Device ID
group1      | 154
group1      | 155
group1      | 156
group2      | 157
group2      | 158
group2      | 159
group3      | 160
group3      | 161
```

So, my question is what is the good way to group date by groupName or groupId and display it like in the table below? As you can see I want to make Group Name to be printed just one time and all devices which belong to this group would be printed in relationship with group name.

```
 Group Name     | Device ID
...........................
    group1      | 154
                | 155
                | 156
...........................
    group2      | 157
                | 158
                | 159
...........................
    group3      | 160
                | 161
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected result can be achieved by recording the previous group name in a `user variable`.

Change `$qry` as below:

```
SELECT 
    g.id as groupId, 
    IF(g.name = @last_name, '', g.name) as groupName, 
    d.device_id, 
    @last_name := g.name
FROM librenms.devices as d
INNER JOIN librenms.device_groups as g
        ON d.hostname LIKE  CONCAT('%', mysql.SPLIT_STR(g.pattern, '\"', 2), '%')
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @last_name := '') param
WHERE g.pattern LIKE '_devices.hostname%'
ORDER BY g.id
```